# Selecting content within the current $(this) selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

You can take a look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18mqn1xg/1/) for an example of what I am trying to do. Here is the Javascript code in question:

```
$("#div_games table tr").each(function(index) {
    var num = index;
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

And the table is from [Hockey-reference.com](http://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_1918_games.html).

I want to organize each row (`tr`) into a csv based pattern. Here is a small example of what the output would look like:

```
Date,Visitor,G,Home,G
1917-12-19,Toronto Arenas,9,Montreal Wanderers,10
```

This is how the first two lines of output would look like.

My question is merely about how I can iterate between each `tr` and then each `td` within there?

I want to do something that looks like this:

```
$("#div_games table tr").each(function(index) {
    $(this ".td").each(function(index) {
        console.log($(this).text + ',');
    });
});
```

I know this code won't work, but is there a way to do something like this? As a side note I am using the node.js based [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), not actually jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).find('td').each(function(index) {
   console.log($(this).text() + ',');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$('td', this).each(function(){});` should do the trick.